# I cant seem to write an Plugin for \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, after-plugin

I am trying to write a plugin for

```
\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource::current
```

using

```
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource">
    <plugin name="firegento_extendedimport_trim_row_data" type="FireGento\ExtendedImport\Plugin\TrimRowData" />
</type>
```

I also tried

```
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\Csv">
    <plugin name="firegento_extendedimport_trim_row_data" type="FireGento\ExtendedImport\Plugin\TrimRowData" />
</type>
```

But in the debugger the interceptor just does not seem to be generated.

Answer (score 3):

The class does not seem to be generated via object manager, but via `new $className` in

```
\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter::factory
```

Comment: OMG, is it....?